# basicNack and basicReject in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

1.what is mean by message in bulk in `basicNack`

> The AMQP 0-9-1 specification defines the basic.reject method that allows clients to reject individual, delivered messages, instructing the broker to either discard them or requeue them. Unfortunately, basic.reject provides no support for negatively acknowledging messages in bulk.

2.is `basicNack` with `multiple` `false` is same as `basicReject`?

```
channel.basicNack(deliveryTag,false,true);

channel.basicReject(deliveryTag,true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; it is effectively the same.